# how to update custom cell label value with respect picker selected value in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6, uipickerview, custom-cell

Update the selected custom cell label value with respect  to the selection of picker view value in my app ? 
NOTE:picker view  having array data of 5 values

Answer (score 0):

Set your view controller as the delegate for the picker, and handle the value changed event.

When the event fires, change the cell label (probably the value stored in an array of labels, right?); then call "reloadData" on the table view.

Comment: actually i need change  the specified cell when i select the value from picker view ,here what am  getting  is  when select from picker view last cell label value is updating ?